# Why does powershell rearrange my output?

Tags: powershell

I build the following `CustomObject` in my function

```
    New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Computername      = $_
        PowerShellVersion = $result[0]
        dotNetVersion     = $result[1]
        sqlnacli          = $result[2]
        redistributable   = $result[3]
    }
```

But the output is like this:

```
PowerShellVersion Computername redistributable sqlnacli dotNetVersion
----------------- ------------ --------------- -------- -------------
3+ OK             SERVERNAME     NOT OK          NOT OK   NOT OK
```

why does PowerShell rearrange the order of my object and how can I force it to take the order I want it to?

Comment: it is a duplicate indeed, but I think the answer to this question is of a higher quality, also the title of the question is more general

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hashtables are not ordered by definition. If you have PowerShell v3.0 or newer, you can use the `[Ordered]` attribute for the hashtable:

```
New-Object PSCustomObject -Property ([Ordered] @{
  Computername      = $_
  PowerShellVersion = $result[0]
  dotNetVersion     = $result[1]
  sqlnacli          = $result[2]
  redistributable   = $result[3]
})
```

In PowerShell v3+ you can also just use the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator:

```
[PSCustomObject] @{
  Computername      = $_
  PowerShellVersion = $result[0]
  dotNetVersion     = $result[1]
  sqlnacli          = $result[2]
  redistributable   = $result[3]
}
```

If you need PowerShell version 2 compatibility, then you can use

```
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
  Computername      = $_
  PowerShellVersion = $result[0]
  dotNetVersion     = $result[1]
  sqlnacli          = $result[2]
  redistributable   = $result[3]
} | Select-Object Computername,PowerShellVersion,dotNetVersion,sqlnacli,redistributable
```

The drawback with this method is if you add properties, you have to remember to add them to `Select-Object`.

An alternative PowerShell v2 or older is to output something (e.g., an empty string) and then use `Select-Object` to create exactly the custom properties you want:

```
$obj = $_
"" | Select-Object `
  @{Name = "Computername";      Expression = {$obj}},
  @{Name = "PowerShellVersion"; Expression = {$result[0]}},
  @{Name = "dotNetVersion";     Expression = {$result[1]}},
  @{Name = "sqlnacli";          Expression = {$result[2]}},
  @{Name = "redistributable";   Expression = {$result[3]}}
```

The only (minor) drawback here is that `$_` in `Select-Object` refers to the the immediately preceding object from which properties are being selected (hence the `$obj = $_` as the first line, to preserve the value).

Comment: hey, you're all around my questions on stackexchange today :). thanks, i'll try

Comment: In PS3+ no need for New-Object or [ordered], simply specify the class `[PSCustomObject]@{ .... }`

Comment: it worked thanks, @wOxxOm yours worked too, so i'll take that one because it's less code. thanks

Comment: I thought the preferred method was using `[PsCustomObject]` accelerator so the script is easy to read and follow.

Answer (score 3):

As @wOxxOm and @Bill_Stewart have mentioned, you need an ordered hashtable to dictate the order and by default, standard hashtables aren't. You can influence the order of a normal hashtable with a select statement, like this.

```
New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
    Computername      = $_
    PowerShellVersion = $result[0]
    dotNetVersion     = $result[1]
    sqlnacli          = $result[2]
    redistributable   = $result[3]
} | Select-Object Computername,PowerShellVersion,dotNetVersion,sqlnacli,redistributable
```

Comment: I'm going to say plus one here for compatibility with earlier flavors of Powershell.