# How to keep the psobjects ordered?

Tags: powershell

I have the following script that gets objects from another scripts and converts it to a pscustomobject

```
& ".\script1.ps1" -ViewConnection "$cinput" -OutVariable xprtOut | Format-Table -Wrap

#converting xprtOut from Arraylist to pscustomobject to be used with ConvertTo-HTMLTable
$Arr = @()
foreach ($Object in $xprtOut) {
    $i = -1
    $arrayListCount = -($Object | gm | Where-Object {$_.MemberType -like "noteproperty"}).Count

    $customObj = New-Object PSCustomObject
    do {
        $customObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name (($Object | gm)[$($i)].Name) -Value ($Object."$(($Object | gm)[$($i)].Name)")
        $i--
    } while ($i -ge $arrayListCount)

    $Arr += $customObj
}
```

it works great and all but i notice the ordering of the objects changes. 
how can i preserve the ordering in the function?

i am trying the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42300930/8397835

```
$Arr += [pscustomobject]$customObj
```

but that doesnt work. i tried placing the cast elsewhere in the function and gave out errors.

> The ordered attribute can be specified only on a hash literal node.

i guess i am not sure where am i supposed to place the `[ordered]` or `[pscutomobject]` in the function since in my case i dont have `@` symbol

Comment: @Drew since you masterminded this function, do you have some suggestions regarding this ordering :)

Comment: instead of using `New-Object` & `Add-Member`, use `[ordered]$Hashtable@{}`, `$Hashtable.Add()`, and finally `[PSCustomObject]$Hashtable` to get things to stay in sequence. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i see. would you mind posting an answer with those modifications?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey would it be $customObj = New-Object PSCustomObject instead of $customObj = New-Object PSCustomObject ....? and  $Hashtable.Add(($Object | gm)[$($i)].Name) -Value ($Object."$(($Object | gm)[$($i)].Name)")   ? and would i replace $Arr += $customObj with [PSCustomObject]$Hashtable?

Comment: nope - DO NOT use `New-Object`. create an **_ordered_** hashtable, iterate thru your collection and add items to that hashtable, then use the PSCO type accelerator create your custom object with `[PSCustomOBject]$Hashtable`. finally, add the PSCO to your new collection.

Comment: can you provide a COMPLETE piece of code? your current sample code requires output from an external script ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey this post is related to this post here, where it explains more in depth how I got this function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878556/how-to-create-pscustomobject-from-arraylist-dynamically

Comment: yep, i saw that. [*grin*] however, i can't replicate anything since you use objects that are not available to me. the question you ask SHOULD be workable via building and _ordered hashtable_ and then converting that in one step into a PSCO. apparently that is not working for you ... and i am unable to test your code since you DID NOT provide the recommended `complete, minimal` code to work with.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey but drew was able to create the function from the information provided :) which means this function just has to be modified for the hash table that's all :)

Comment: then you will need to hope that someone better at this - perhaps `Drew` - drops by to help. i can't do anything more than tell you what SHOULD work ... since your code is not complete and therefore cannot be tested by me.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Theo provided a beautiful intuitive solution :)

Comment: kool! i am one of those who needs more concrete samples to do anything more than a basic loop ... [*grin*] glad to know you got it working as needed!

Comment: @Lee_Dailey np, totally understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is (as I see it) all about copying objects properties while keeping the property order in place.
The `Get-Member` (gm) cmdlet does not keep the order in which the properties are set in the input objects, but iterating through the [PSObject.Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.properties?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) does.

For PowerShell version 3.0 and above:

```
$Arr = foreach ($Object in $xprtOut) {
    # create an empty PSCustomObject
    $copy = [PSCustomObject]::new()
    # loop through the properties in order and add them to $copy object
    $Object.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object { 
        $copy | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value
    }
    # emit the copied object so it adds to the $Arr array
    $copy
}
```

If you have PowerShell < 3.0, use the code below:

```
$Arr = foreach ($Object in $xprtOut) {
    # create an ordered dictionary object
    $copy = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
    # loop through the properties in order and add them to the ordered hash
    $Object.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object { 
        $copy.Add($_.Name, $_.Value)   # or use: $copy[$($_.Name)] = $_.Value
    }
    # emit a PSObject with the properties ordered, so it adds to the $Arr array
    New-Object PSObject -Property $copy
}
```

Comment: Theo, this solution is soo much more condensed and intuitive and keeps things ordered! i do have a question...with or without $Arr = @() declaration, your code is working. how is that possible and how is $Arr an array if its not defined already with @()? thank you!

Comment: @Cataster That's the beauty of PowerShell. It has the ability of capturing the output of a loop directly into a variable. You will end up with either a single object (if the loop iterated just one 'thing') or an array of objects as in this case. Furthermore, it is also much faster that creating an empty array first and add elements to it inside the loop.

Comment: That is a beauty indeed. im growing in love with powershell more and more everyday. i wanna try getting into the GUI powershell because that to me is so interesting. one reason i love powershell is because its native to windows. you just laucnh a console without having to download anything at all. it wont take forever like it does launching visual studio lol. and i can do everything from notepad++ :)

Comment: @Cataster [:thumbsup:]

Comment: @Theo _"but iterating through the PSObject.Properties does"_ any documentation reference for this?

Comment: @OhadSchneider Can't find documentation in a hurry, but every object has a hidden PSObject object attached to it. One of its properties is the `Properties` array property with which you can perform a loop to get the root objects property Name and its Value in the exact order in which they appear.

Comment: @Theo I guess my difficulty is that "property appearance order" does not seem to be defined or guaranteed in any of the docs I saw. Opened this issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/9472

Answer (score 1):

You can add [Ordered], so the list will be ordered while exporting to csv.

```
 $data = [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{  
    "UsersObjectId"                 = $user.ObjectId
    "SyncedOnPrem"                  = $user.DirSyncEnabled
    "UserDisplayName"               = $user.DisplayName
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Creating shallow copies of an object is as simple as using the [`.Copy()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.copy?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#system-management-automation-psobject-copy). Because these are copies the order is also ensured.

```
$Arr = foreach ($Object in $xprtOut) {
    $Object.PSObject.Copy()
}
```